# BeautifulSoup, 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, findall

I read other threads related to my issue but it did not solve the problem.

```
<h2 class="tabellen_ueberschrift al">Cards</h2>
<div class="fl" style="width:49%;">     
<table class="tabelle_grafik lh" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
            <th class="al" colspan="3">CA Osasuna</th>              
        </tr>

            <td class="s10 al">
                <a href="/en/sisi/profil/spieler_51713.html" class="fb s10" title="Sisi">Sisi</a>
                <br />
                26.  min. 2. yellow card, Time wasting              </td>
        </tr>
```

I want to get all the `a` tags (there will be several) within the table so my code is this:

```
header = soup.find('h2', text="Cards")
cards_table = header.find_next_siblings(limit=2)
for row in cards_table.find_all('a'):
    print row
```

This raises me

```
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

`cards_table` is a table and I iterate over it with the `for` loop so not sure why this is causing the error. Ideas please?

Comment: If this is solved, then to close the question off you should post your solution as an answer, and accept it...

Comment: the only snag is I think the question might have to be 48 hours old though...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, the code was missing one line:

```
for line in cards_table:
    for row in line.find_all('a'):
        print row
```

`cards_table` is a list so we had to iterate over it before we could use the `find_all` method for the table.